# matlab classes and data management

Tags: matlab, class

I have these types of classes in Matlab

DataReader -> data
Analyser -> results -> needs data
Plotter -> needs data and results.

```
reader = ImageReader(processFolder);
filter = SignalFilter(reader, parameter);
position = SignalPosition(reader, filter, parameter);
plotter = PlotResults(reader, position, parameter);
```

I am not happy with this design. I cpp I would pass pointers around not data. In Matlab I pass large chunks of data and create copies.

How can I avoid to pass the data to the classes, but have a way to access the data?
How would this be solved in Matlab?

Comment: You can't avoid it. That's how Matlab works. No references, no pointers.

Comment: MATLAB does have [handle classes](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle-class.html), making your classes "handle classes" lets you access them by reference. You could also make the "reader" and "plotter" classes properties of your "analyser", so that their methods are accessed via the analyser, which stores the data and relevant options like "parameter"

Comment: MATLAB does “lazy copying”: all copies reference the same data until you attempt to change one of the copies; that is when the data is actually copied. So passing data into functions (by value) or storing a copy in your class doesn’t take up any extra space. The handle classes Wolfie referenced are useful if you need to pass data by reference (though  this is typically not necessary) or when holding a resource that cannot be copied (the handle of a window or an open file).

Comment: Also, if you pass pointers around in C++, you really should look into references, `std::move` and copy elision. C++ is much better with stack-allocated objects passed by reference. I haven’t used `new` in 8 years!